# What's the most efficient way to recast a float pointer as a double pointer in C?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, objective-c++

I'm working with DSP in code that's a mashup of objective C++ and C.

The CoreAudio framework is providing me buffers of audio sample data as float pointers

e.g. `float *bufferData = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * 1024);`

The C function that I'm calling to do processing on the sample data requires a pointer of type **double**.

```
double returnAValue(double *sampleData, int samplecount);
```

What's the most CPU efficient way of converting my float pointer into a double pointer before passing it to this function?

Comment: I don't see anything other than a recasting to convert it.  You will catch flak on casting the malloc(), BTW.

Comment: There is no _most_ _efficient_ way as pointer conversion does not get compiled. Did you mean you wanted to convert each float in the array into a double?

Comment: Could you rewrite or replace returnAValue to take floats?

Comment: No amount of casting gets this done. You have to convert.

Comment: @jim I can't re-write `returnAValue` - it's part of a very large 3-rd party library and I don't want to start tugging at threads.

Comment: @Jim Could you explain what you mean by "You will catch flak on casting the malloc(), BTW"

Comment: Many folks insist you should not cast a malloc() in C, but you MUST cast it in C++.

Comment: I think it's a <teapot>tempest</teapot> because, while unnecessary, the downsides of casting a malloc() in C are minimal, and if you are working in both C and C++, you don't have to remember what to do.

Comment: The most efficient way is `doublePtr = NULL;`.

Comment: FWIW: In C++ you should say `float * bufferData = new float[1024];` rather than calling malloc then later `delete[] bufferData` rather than free(bufferData)

Comment: @DaleWilson - thanks, is this just an idiom thing or is there a performance difference?

Comment: Try initialising non pods with malloc.

Comment: @bodacious there's no performance difference, it's just "the C++ way"  Notice that no casting or void pointer assignments are needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the many functions that the Accelerate framework provides is `vDSP_vspdp`, which you can use like this:

```
float * singleBuf;
float * doubleBuf = malloc(nElements * sizeof(double));
vDSP_vspdp(singleBuf, 1, doubleBuf, 1, nElements);
```

If you're doing any kind of DSP programming on a Mac, you could save tons of time and gain tons of efficiency by learning about vDSP, CBLAS, and other Accelerate framework APIs. These APIs tend to go through the processor's vector unit (SSE, etc) and know about memory hinting, so they tend to be much more efficient than what you'd typically code by hand.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the type of the pointer does not change the type of the underlying data.   If you are trying to link together two packages that expect different contents in the buffers, you are going to have to copy the data from one buffer to another, converting on the way.

So your question is: given a buffer full of floats, how do you convert it to a buffer full of doubles?   A simple for loop is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks - I'm using a for loop just now but since they're costly, I wanted to see if there was a more efficient way to do it

Comment: @bodacious - a for loop is expensive? If you are really pushed (maybe as its DSP) then unwind the loop - say do 8 or 16 conversions per iteration (of the form `*doublePtr++ = (double)*floatPtr++`)